# How will i save a pdf that i am editing inside html to the server in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, nestjs

I am creating a react app which will load a PDFForm from the server and it will save the edited PDFForm from the browser back to the server. I am able to get the Load function to work as expected but I am not really sure how to go about saving the PDF.

My immediate question is how do i track changes made on my pdf from browser as there is no onchange event for embed tag

Any help would be appreciated :)

[image: app demo]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you but what I am trying to do is to save the pdf as a byte array to my server when i click on save pdf button. Currently I can save the pdf but it is saving it as the original pdf that I loaded. I would ideally like to have a functionality like onchange for embed which will keep track of the changed pdf in lets say a state variable and save it to server on click of save